# What to do if my linear model doesn't have neither homoscedasticity or residuals normal distribution?

Tags: r, mixed-model, aic, glmm

`lme.resultsA <- lme(root~factor(week)*factor(fertilizer), random=~week|factor(planti), data=results, control=lmeControl(maxIter=1000, msMaxIter=1000, niterEM=1000, opt='optim'))`

Details of the Model:

- They are Repeated measurements.
- Length root (in cm) registered each 2, 4, 6 and 8 weeks.
- root: Root Length in cm.
- factor(week): 2, 4, 6, 8.
- factor(fertilizer): control and added
- N°planti: 1, 2, 3, ... 12

According to AIC, it is the best model, but statistical tests (and graphics?) show that it hasn't got neither homoscedasticity or residuals normal distribution. Furthermore, errors are autocorrelated.

What do you suggest me to do next?
In case the best option would be to delete such five numbers to fit residuals normal distribution (Q-Q plot). How is it suggested to find and delete them?.

By the way, please, let me know if I am doing these two Levene tests correctly:

leveneTest(residuals(lme.resultsA) ~ results$fertilizer)

leveneTest(residuals(lme.resultsA) ~ results$planti)

This is just my model LMM.[image: My model hasn't got either homoscedasticity nor residuals normal distribution. Furthermore, errors are autocorrelated]

Than you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

The model appears to be quite good.

From the plots on the question, I do not see much evidence that the residuals are not normally distributed, or of heteroskedasticity. It is pointless to look for a perfectly normal distribution.

You don't include a acf/pacf plot so I can't comment on autocorrelation, but if present then use the `corAR1` or one of the other correlation structure functions available in `lme`.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks !